# Log out error after moving wordpress

Tags: wordpress, logout

I moved wordpress forom iszablony.pl/wordpress to iszablony.pl using this method:
1) change site url in settings
2) copie index.php and .htaccess to main folder
3) move wp-config.php
4) edit require('./wp-blog-header.php'); to require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
5) update direct links in settings

Everything was fine, to time when i tried to log out.
Insted of logout and redirect i get this adress:

```
http://www.iszablony.pl/%E2%80%9Dhttp:/www.iszablony.pl/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iszablony.pl%2Fmoje-konto%2F&_wpnonce=128c43656c%E2%80%9D
```

in browser %E2%80%9D is " so the adress looks like that:
http://www.iszablony.pl/"http:/www.iszablony.pl/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iszablony.pl%2Fmoje-konto%2F&_wpnonce=128c43656c"

what should i do now ? how to fix this ? please help.

important information could be that before that migration, accidentally i change URL of WordPress adress in settings and refresh iszablony.pl. Than in database i changed siteurl to http://www.iszablony.pl/wordpress
Now i have siteurl `http://www.iszablony.pl/wordpress` and home `http://www.iszablony.pl`

i noticed that contact form doesnt work too.

how to handle it ?

Comment: `%E2%80%9D` decodes to `"` so it's almost looking like you've got an extra character somewhere that's preventing your address from resolving properly, and is appending as a relative link. Search through what you edited and look for a stray `"`

Comment: unfortunately contact form 7 doesn't work too. IMO its the same problem (but where it is ?).

Answer (score 1):

WordPress save the URL config in the database, maybe you need to change it.

Some scripts change it only defining the new domain, and the script executes the db queries

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-moving-script-move-to-another-host-or-domain

Comment: i think that's the problem, somewhere in db, there is unchanged url. 
Before using this script i should change home url, move wp-config.php to /wordpress, delate .htaccess and index.php in main folder (iszablony.pl) ?

(theoretically, should after this change, logout and contact form 7 work?)

Answer (score 0):

Please change site_url and home values to

http://www.iszablony.pl instead of http://www.iszablony.pl/wordpress

in "wp_options" table

Comment: but wordpress core files are still in iszablony.pl/wordpress